# Object orbitting 2D circle java

Tags: java

I'm using this code to make a square that orbits a circle . When I use it however the `rect()`; is quite far away from the circumference of the circle, I would like to make it closer. All variables are floats. `YPos` and `XPos` are the x and y of the circles origin.

```
charx = XPos[0] + cos(angle)*Sizes[0];
chary = YPos[0] + sin(angle)*Sizes[0];
angle += 0.1;
fill(255,255,255);
rect(charx, chary, 10,10);}
```

Any idea what I should change?
This is probably something very simple, but I'm very new to Java.

Comment: define: `is quite far away from the circumference of the circle, i would like to make it closer.`  more exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ideas: 1) Make Sizes[0] smaller. 2) Try rect(charx-5, chary-5, 10, 10);